How to correctly call a main window C++ with Qt 5, which is resizeable
This project ought to be a minesweeper game.
I've tried QWidget, QApplication and QMainWindow at position I and II in my class and constructor declaration, but none of the worked and I'm pretty sure that the error comes from the class or constructor declaration.
main.cpp
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QWidget>

#include "fensterHaupt.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv []) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    int k = 2, m = 3, n = 12;

    FensterHaupt fh (k, m, n, &app);
    fh.show ();

    return app.exec ();
}

(relevant part of) fensterHaupt.h
#ifndef FENSTERHAUPT_H
#define FENSTERHAUPT_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QTime>

#include <ui_fensterHaupt.h>

#include "feld.h"

class FensterHaupt : public // position I
QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public :
    FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication // position II
*parent = 0);
};

#endif // FENSTERHAUPT_H

(relevant part of) fensterHaupt.cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRandomGenerator>

#include "fensterHaupt.h"

FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication // position II
*parent) : QWidget // position I
(parent) {
    hohe = h - 1;
    breite = b - 1;
    restlicheMinen = minen = m;

    uiFensterHaupt.setupUi (this);

    bool mineSetzen = false;
    restminenzahl = minen;
    int felderanzahl = breite * hohe;

    connect (uiFensterHaupt.schalterPause,
        SIGNAL (clicked () ), this, SLOT (spielPausieren () ) );

    connect (uiFensterHaupt.schalterNeu,
        SIGNAL (clicked () ), this, SLOT (eintragSuchen () ) );


    for (int br = 0; br < b; ++ br) {
        for (int ho = 0; ho < h; ++ ho) {
            mineSetzen = minenPlatzieren (felderanzahl);
            uiFensterHaupt.spielfeldRaster->addWidget (new Feld (br, ho, mineSetzen, spielfeld), br, ho);
            felderanzahl --;
        }
    }
    spielfeld = uiFensterHaupt.spielfeldRaster;
}

I'd say that Feld.cpp and Feld.h aren't relevant for this case. (But to give a MWE, here it is.)
Feld.h
#ifndef FELD_H
#define FELD_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>

class Feld : public QPushButton {
    Q_OBJECT

public :
    Feld (int zeile, int spalte, bool mine, QWidget *parent = 0);

    bool vermint ();
    void verminen ();

//public slots :
signals :
    void vermarkieren ();
    QList<int> feldAufdecken ();
    QList<int> feldMarkieren ();
    QList<int> feldAbwischen ();
    void feldSprengen ();
    void mineFreilegen (int zeile, int spalte);

public :
    bool mine = false;
    bool explodiert = false;
    int zeile = 0, spalte = 0;
    QList<int> koordinaten;

    int nachbarn = 0;
    bool markiert = false;
    bool aufgedeckt = false;
    int inhalt = 0;
    QLabel *beschriftung = new QLabel (" ", this);
};

#endif // FELD_H

Feld.cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "feld.h"
#include "fensterHaupt.h"

Feld::Feld (int zeile, int spalte, bool mine, QWidget *parent) : QPushButton (parent) {
    this->zeile = zeile;
    this->spalte = spalte;
    koordinaten << zeile << spalte;
    this->mine = mine;

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout (this);
    layout->addWidget (beschriftung);
    setLayout (layout);
}

bool Feld::vermint () {
    return mine;
}

void Feld::verminen () {
    inhalt = 9;
    mine = true;
}

void Feld::vermarkieren () {
    markiert = ! markiert;
}

QList<int> Feld::feldAufdecken () {
    if (! aufgedeckt) {
        markiert = false;
        aufgedeckt = true;
        FensterHaupt* fh = qobject_cast<FensterHaupt*> (parent () );

        switch (inhalt) {
            case 9 : {
                fh->spielfeldSprengen (zeile, spalte);
                emit fh->spielSprengen (zeile, spalte);
                break;
            } case 0 : {
                emit fh->felderAufdecken (zeile, spalte);
                break;
            } default : {
                feldAufdecken ();
            }
        }
    }

    return koordinaten;
}

QList<int> Feld::feldMarkieren () {
    markiert = true;
    return koordinaten;
}

QList<int> Feld::feldAbwischen () {
    markiert = false;
    return koordinaten;
}

void Feld::feldSprengen () {
    if (mine) {
        aufgedeckt = true;
        markiert = false;
        beschriftung->setText ("e");
        // setLayout or so! ###
        ;
    } else {
qDebug () << "Feld::feldSprengen: Fehler beim Sprengversuch von Feld" << zeile << spalte << ".";
    }
}

void Feld::mineFreilegen (int z, int s) {
    if (z == zeile && s == spalte) {
        beschriftung->setText ("e");
    } else {
        if (mine) {
            beschriftung->setText ("m");
        } else if (nachbarn) {
            beschriftung->setText (QString (nachbarn) );
        } else {
            beschriftung->setText (" ");
        }
    }
}

EDIT
What I'm trying to achieve
Having a main window, which appears by starting the compiled program, with a rectangled area in which a grid of Feld objects is built up with respect to width and height given in FensterHaupt fh (k, m, n, &app); in main.cpp. In the next step, the window should adjust its width and height dependent on the size of the QGridLayout spielfeld, which is going to be changed by user input later on.
The problems I've encountered
It seems that I declare my function(s) with a different set of variables (parameters) than I define them with.
Seemingly, I try to make my custom classes inheriting from some QObject which isn't intended to be used for what I'm trying to use them for.
Although my files contain more code, I just brought up the functions which seem to trouble around. My main.cpp is unabridged.
my CLI output
$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o fensterHaupt.o fensterHaupt.cpp
fensterHaupt.cpp: In constructor ‘FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt(int, int, int, QApplication*)’:
fensterHaupt.cpp:6:89: error: no matching function for call to ‘QWidget::QWidget(QApplication*&)’
    6 | FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication *parent) : QWidget (parent) {
      |                                                                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qdialog.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QDialog:1,
                 from fensterHaupt.h:4,
                 from fensterHaupt.cpp:4:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:693:5: note: candidate: ‘QWidget::QWidget(QWidgetPrivate&, QWidget*, Qt::WindowFlags)’
  693 |     QWidget(QWidgetPrivate &d, QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f);
      |     ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:693:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:215:14: note: candidate: ‘QWidget::QWidget(QWidget*, Qt::WindowFlags)’
  215 |     explicit QWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
      |              ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:215:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QApplication*’ to ‘QWidget*’
  215 |     explicit QWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
fensterHaupt.cpp:20:33: error: cannot convert ‘FensterHaupt*’ to ‘QMainWindow*’
   20 |         uiFensterHaupt.setupUi (this);
      |                                 ^~~~
      |                                 |
      |                                 FensterHaupt*
In file included from fensterHaupt.h:8:
./ui_fensterHaupt.h:58:31: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Ui_FensterHaupt::setupUi(QMainWindow*)’
   58 |     void setupUi(QMainWindow *FensterHaupt)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
fensterHaupt.cpp:42:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘Feld::Feld(int&, int&, bool&, QGridLayout*&)’
   42 |                         uiFensterHaupt.spielfeldRaster->addWidget (new Feld (br, ho, mineSetzen, spielfeld), br, ho);
      |                                                                                                           ^
In file included from fensterHaupt.h:10:
feld.h:18:9: note: candidate: ‘Feld::Feld(int, int, bool, QWidget*)’
   18 |         Feld (int zeile, int spalte, bool mine, QWidget *parent = 0);
      |         ^~~~
feld.h:18:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘QGridLayout*’ to ‘QWidget*’
   18 |         Feld (int zeile, int spalte, bool mine, QWidget *parent = 0);
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:458: fensterHaupt.o] Fehler 1

Changing the lines
class FensterHaupt : public QWidget { in fensterHaupt.h to
class FensterHaupt : public QApplication { and
FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication *parent) : QWidget (parent) { to
FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication *parent) : QApplication (parent) { in fensterHaupt.cpp leads to
$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o 3.o 3.cpp
3.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
3.cpp:16:12: error: ‘class FensterHaupt’ has no member named ‘show’
   16 |         fh.show ();
      |            ^~~~
make: *** [Makefile:443: 3.o] Fehler 1

.
As G.M. suggests, changing FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QWidget *parent) : QWidget (parent) { in fensterHaupt.cpp and FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QWidget *parent = nullptr); in fensterHaupt.h leads to
Info: creating stash file /home/jschreck/duales-software-engineering/user-interface-design/Übungen/3/.qmake.stash
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic fensterHaupt.ui -o ui_fensterHaupt.h
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic fensterHilfe.ui -o ui_fensterHilfe.h
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o 3.o 3.cpp
3.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
3.cpp:15:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt(int&, int&, int&, QApplication*)’
   15 |         FensterHaupt fh (k, m, n, &app); // In diesem Fenster spielt sich das meiste ab (Hauptfenster).
      |                                       ^
In file included from 3.cpp:8:
fensterHaupt.h:18:9: note: candidate: ‘FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt(int, int, int, QWidget*)’
   18 |         FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
fensterHaupt.h:18:53: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘QApplication*’ to ‘QWidget*’
   18 |         FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
      |                                            ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:443: 3.o] Fehler 1

.

"but none of the worked" tells us absolutely nothing.  Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve and the problems you've encountered.  At the very least QWidget(*parent) in your FensterHaupt constructor's initializer list should be QWidget(parent).

The error message from the compiler seems pretty clear:  you've declared the constructor as FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication *parent = 0) but have tried to define it as FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication parent) -- note QApplication vs QApplication *.  Change the implementation to FensterHaupt::FensterHaupt (int h, int b, int m, QApplication *parent).

The thing is that I tried different "QClass"es at position I(I), but afai can remeḿber, they all gave me an error message stating that there was "no matching function for call".

Ok, so the fix I suggested won't work (sorry, was paying attention to the wrong thing).  As per the documentation, the parent parameter must be a valid QWidget * or nullptr.  In your case just let it default to the null pointer.

But the point seems to lie in ) : QWidget (parent) as the error msg indicates…

Your FensterHaupt constructor should be declared as FensterHaupt(int h, int b, int m, QWidget *parent = nullptr) and implemented accordingly.

Please think about what you're doing.  As stated, your constructor should take (and use) a QWidget * so there's no point in passing it a QApplication * (which doesn't inherit from QWidget).  How familiar are you with either of C++ or Qt?

I have some experience with C**, but not too much and I'm new to Qt.
